# User Restriction in ENSEMBLE

Tags: intersystems-ensemble

HI friends
i develop a application in ENSEMBLE [2009], in that i restrict some user to access all links except "Ensemble Management Portal" i done this by changing roles for that particular user as Home->securitymanagement->Users->Editusers->roles. But when i logged in in to the system managenet portal and change the namespace it's logged out , Again i try to login means i got the Error Access Denied , Please help me to find the solution
Thansk in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you just don't have enough privileges to access specific namespace. Just remove $NAMESPACE=something from URL when you try to login again.